# How to validate an optional field?

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a phone number field in redux-form. I want this field to be optional (defaults to '' if the user does not submit a value), but if they do enter a value, it should check to make sure it is a valid phone number.

The issue I'm having is that my form's submit button is currently disabled and tied to whether my Redux form is valid. I'm not sure why this won't pass as valid if it has a default '' value. It does seem to change valid to true once something is entered into the phone number field.

How can I check for validation if something is submitted, else pass along '' and still have my form be valid? Thanks!

**Validation**

```
const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};

  if (!/^[0-9-.() ]*$/i.test(values.phoneNumber)) {
    errors.phoneNumber = 'Invalid phone number';
  }

  return errors;
};
```

**Form Field**

```
<div className={classNames(['form-field', {
  'error': phoneNumber.touched && phoneNumber.error,}])}
>
  <label className="form-field-title">
    Phone Number 
      {
        phoneNumber.touched && 
        phoneNumber.error && 
        <span>{phoneNumber.error}</span>
      }
  </label>

    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-input-field"
      {...phoneNumber}
      value={phoneNumber.value || ''}
    />
</div>
```

**Submit Button**

```
<button
  type="submit"
  className="btn dark"
  disabled={!this.props.valid}
>
  <span className="submit-text">
    {this.state.submitText}
  </span>
  <i className="fa fa-check"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and test to see if `phoneNumber` is anything at all before testing the RegEx.

```
if (values.phoneNumber && !/^[0-9-.() ]*$/i.test(values.phoneNumber)) {
    errors.phoneNumber = 'Invalid phone number';
  }
```

If `values.phoneNumber` is empty, then your error object will return empty, and the valid prop should be true.